# How to Make a C++ Wrapper for a C Linked List

Tags: c++, c, wrapper, encapsulation, doubly-linked-list

I've implemented a linked list in C with many functions to help ease its manipulation.
I don't want to port this functionality to C++ so I'm trying to create a simple Wrapper Class that calls the original functions internally, and manipulates the **C** linked list internally as well.

For most of the functionality, the wrapper code works well. There is one problem, however. The C linked list structure has pointers to the next and the previous **C** linked list structures, and I want to be able to get the C++ equivalent class pointers instead ..

How can I do that ?

E.x: There is a C function that gets the linked list in the chain at an index. The Original function would do something like this:

```
struct _linkedlist *LinkedList_get(struct _linkedlist * list, const unsigned long index)
{ /* Gets the index'th linked list in the chain as a pointer */
    if ((list) == NULL) return NULL;
    if (index >= LinkedList_get_depth(list))
        return NULL;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < index; list = list->next, ++i);
    return list;
}
```

The function clearly returns a pointer to the linked list C struct. What I want to do is get a pointer to the C++ linked list wrapper object.

The whole purpose of this is that I can make an object oriented wrapper (the C++ interface) around a purely functional interface (the C interface) without altering the original source (the C version).

Comment: `C++ equivalent class pointers instead ..` What does this mean? Nearly any C program is already valid C++. It all sounds rather pointless anyway because C++ already has a `std::list`.

Comment: @user657267 I believe the OP wants a way to map from the C structure's address to the address of the corresponding C++ wrapper.

Comment: @user657267: I want to try to wrap my version of it, so I'm not using `std::list`. By __C++ equivalent class pointers__, I mean C++ object pointers in place of the struct pointers.

Comment: Is there a way to "hook" the C implementation's memory allocation somehow? And second point, can you clarify if you're going to recompile the C source as C++, or link C++ to object files/library compiled from the C source?

Comment: Why not throw the C code in the bin. The STL has one done without any pain

Comment: @AmrAyman What's the point of wrapping the C code if you still want to expose raw pointers in your wrapper interface? Maybe you should learn how to use `std::list` first.

Comment: @EdHeal I would say the question is actually quite interesting, if we mentally replace "a linked list" by "a nontrivial node-based data structure which doesn't exist in the standard C++ library" (and there are *lots* of those).

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Is your C linked list tied to a specific type of value, or can it store data of an "arbitrary" type (e.g. `void*` + size)?

Comment: @Angew: 1. You mean attach a callback to `malloc` calls ? I don't know if that's possible painlessly (though valgrind does that). 2. The C Code will be linked. 3. The value of the list is `void *`, so yes it can be any type of pointer.

Comment: @DDrmmr: I'm not going to expose any pointers in the interface, I'm talking about the wrapper internals.

Comment: @AmrAyman I meant more like "Does the code use `malloc` or an externally supplied `void* (*useThisToAllocateMemory)(size_t)`. So I assume the answer is `malloc`, which for me means non-hookable.

Comment: @AmrAyman Then why do you need "C++ object pointers in place of the struct pointers"?

Comment: @DDrmmr: All of what I said was meant to be in the implementation of the wrapper itself. The interface (the c++ class) isn't going to __expose__ pointers to the wrapper user ..

Comment: @AmrAyman In that case I would recommend **not** wrapping the 'node' struct, but instead implement a list class and corresponding (const)iterator class that keep pointers to the node struct internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned in comments that your C linked list stores an arbitrary value type (as `void*`). Therefore, it should be fairly trivial for the C++ wrapper to store extra information in that value type. This extra information could be the pointer to the corresponding C++ wrapper.

You haven't shown your code, so I will just show the idea in a generic fashion:

```
// This is the original C interface
struct C_Node;

void* c_getValue(struct C_Node *node);

struct C_Node* c_insertAfter(struct C_Node *node, void *value);


// This is the C++ wrapper
template <class T>
class Node
{
  C_Node *cNode;

  typedef std::pair<T, Node*> ProxyValueType;

  explicit Node(C_Node *cNode) : cNode(cNode)
  {
    static_cast<ProxyValueType*>(c_getValue(cNode))->second = this;
  }

public:
  T& getValue() const
  { return static_cast<ProxyValueType*>(c_getValue(cNode))->first; }

  Node* insertAfter(T value)
  {
    ProxyValueType *proxy = new ProxyValueType(T, nullptr);
    C_Node *newNode = c_insertAfter(cNode, proxy);
    return new Node(newNode);
  }
};
```

Of course, the above as written is *bad* C++, as it uses owning raw pointers etc. Treat it as a demonstration of the idea, not as pastable code.

Comment: Well, to think of it, I thought of putting the object itself in the `value` pointer of the C list, but after thinking for a second about it, I thought it was bad. I think that's the only way after all ;) About your code, I didn't expect modern c++ code to be able to wrap C code that makes intensive use of pointers anyway ..

Comment: @AmrAyman You could always wrap stuff in some of smart pointer; perhaps one with a whacky deleter, but still safer than a "don't forget to `delete` me exactly once" raw pointer.